# How to loop to retrieve images from web with NSData where an array holds url strings?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, url, xcode5

using URL in objective C is always misleading. Percent Encoding works in one situation and not in another. I just can't get why its so difficult to work with URL in objective C when other languages like C# never complain about such matters. 
    [NSData dataWithContentOfURL:] retrieves image if url is hard-coded, but not when it is provided from some variable that is retrieved at runtime. Percent Encoding is not working here. Whats the best way to handle URL in dynamic situation like this and others too?

```
NSString *logoString = [feeds[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"logo"];

NSURL *logoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",logoString]];

NSData *logoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:logoURL];

UIImage *logoImage = [UIImage imageWithData:logoData];
imageView.image = logoImage;
```

percent encoding code:

```
NSString *encodedString = (NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
                        NULL,
                        (CFStringRef)unencodedString,
                        NULL,
                        (CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",
                        kCFStringEncodingUTF8 );
```

Comment: Make sure the variable passed is the same the server is expecting ,you can log in runtime what is your connection request to find any string format error. You can also use    URLstr =[URLstr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];  , if there is some space problem.  Also can you be specific about the problem, are doing setHTTPMethod:@"POST" ?

Comment: I am using NSData.I have updated qs with code.

Comment: Are you sure that Percent Encoding is the problem. For retrieving images, its better to use NSURLConnection api which is asynchronous by default. This will allow lazy loading of your images and will free the UI from getting freezed. There are lot of tuts on lazy loading images from server for ref.

Comment: I shall look at NSURLConnection. By the way while percent Encoding what do you generally do? Is it something like shown above? Can you provide what you do while working with URL? I am enjoying iOS programming but I always get stuck when working with URL.